# How to remove border from jquery mobile radio buttons

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I would like to retain some formating but remove the border of jQuery radio buttons. It would also be very nice to have a theme that has no shadows. Is there a clean version of jQM? I used the themeroller but I still get shadows in text and found no way to remove the styling...

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" data-mini="true">
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="none">
      <input type="radio" name="" id="Select_0" value="" />
      <label for="Select_0">option1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="" id="Select_1" value="" />
      <label for="Select_1">option1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="" id="Select_2" value="" />
      <label for="Select_2">option1</label>
      <input type="radio" name="" id="Select_3" value="" />
      <label for="Select_3">option1</label>
    </fieldset>
  </div> 
</div>
```

[image: what I want]
[image: radio problems]

The blue is what I want to have the green is what I have right now.
The blue is from http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2006/06/11/fancy-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ I want to replace the jQM style for the fancy-checkboxes.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive on what you meant by borders?

Comment: Please show a picture and some code.

Comment: updated with code and picture

Comment: Hi Adam, you mean to say no shadows to buttons only or some other elments too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some styles you can add to the bottom to get pretty close to what you're looking for.(built ontop of twsansbury's answer)

```
/* remove rounded corners */
.ui-btn-corner-all {
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

/* remove border between each item */
.ui-btn-inner{
  border: 0;
}

/* remove margin between items */
fieldset .ui-radio {
  margin: 0;
}

/* change background, remove other border, unbold text */
.ui-btn-up-a, .ui-btn-hover-a, .ui-btn-down-a {
  background: #4f83bc;
  background-image: none;
  border: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}


/* change color of radio background */
.ui-checkbox-on .ui-icon, .ui-radio-on .ui-icon {
  background-color: #456;
}
```

Result:

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/bJHrM/7/

Comment: That is pretty close to the desired effect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Overriding certain styles with !important on you own css should suffice (eg. .nameofJqueryStyle {border: none !important;} ). You can figure out the styles you want to target using either FireBug or Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: There seems to be allot of margin used to style the radio and checkbuttons... it's quite hard to remove it all...

Answer (score 2):

I was able to remove borders around radio and checkbox buttons, as well as remove the text shadows by placing the following css at the bottom of my jquery mobile theme:

```
.ui-checkbox .ui-btn-inner,
.ui-radio .ui-btn-inner
{
  border: none;
}

.ui-checkbox .ui-btn-up-a,
.ui-checkbox .ui-btn-hover-a,
.ui-checkbox .ui-btn-down-a,
.ui-radio .ui-btn-up-a,
.ui-radio .ui-btn-hover-a,
.ui-radio .ui-btn-down-a
{
  border: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a picture or fiddle? Thanks!

Comment: I used [jquerymobile themeroller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/?ver=1.1.0&style_id=20120611-89), only setting the color.  Downloaded it, modified the html slightly with your html, and created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJHrM/2/).  At the bottom of the css, I commented out the style to remove the borders and text-shadow.  This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJHrM/3/) is based on the first, but the code is no longer commented out, removing the text shadow and border.  Also, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bJHrM/1/) is the example with the options being in the same control group.

Comment: Hi twsansbury hte issue is that you still have the blue box, What I want is to get rid of the box element altogether and apply a different style. I want to remove the jQuery look from the select boxes altogether.

Comment: you just need to play around with the CSS more. this answer is a great starting point I'm sure you can figure out the rest of the CSS if you just use the element inspector in your browser to see what styles are being applied by jquerymobile and then override them.

Comment: Sorry, I am having problems understanding the final desired result.  Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bJHrM/6/) a step in the correct direction?  It removes the background from the buttons, as the previous background gradient gave it a hard-edge between buttons.  The tricky point with styling is that the normal radio button is always there, and need to be drawn over.  To do this, use the `.ui-icon-radio-off` and `.ui-icon-radio-on` classes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a data-theme that you haven't created. For example, if you've created Swatch A, B, C and D, use:

```
    <input type="radio" name="" id="Select_0" value="" data-theme="e" />
```

This will do if you try to get rid of the borders but you will see a background image on the checkbox. To get rid of that, create a stylesheet what you will use to override the jquery mobile styles and include in after the jquery mobile stylesheets. 
For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/MyApp/Content/themes/CustomTheme.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/MyApp/Content/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.css" />
 <!-- Custom stylesheet overriding styles -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/MyApp/Content/Custom.css" />
```

Then, in Custom.css, insert the following:

```
.ui-checkbox-off .ui-icon, .ui-radio-off .ui-icon
{
  background-color: #ADADAD;
}
```

where the background-color is the color of your choice when the radiobutton is in inactive state.

I was trying to achieve the same thing as you but for one checkbox/radiobutton and this worked for me so I thought I would share :)